# Wordpress Avata Theme Team Section Issue - Unexpected space between photos

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, spaces, photos

I've got problem with my Wordpress page. I use Avata theme and in the section named "Team" I've got problem with unexpected huge spaces between objects in this section. I want photos to show one after another as it does in every second line.

Link to page where the issue appears:
http://podsmerkami.pl

EDIT: I want to told you also, that when I turn on "full width" mode in this section it looks well on my MacBook in Safari but still crashes on Windows and other browsers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add css code

```
img.img-responsive {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Too soon. I have to set header and content style of this section too. I set min height of both and now it works fine.